# Get Local Directory Path and All File Names Inside (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, parsing, directory

I'm creating an IOS app with swift and I'm having a lot of trouble and cannot seem to find the answer.

I have a giant (local) folder that contains a lot of JSONs in my app directory. The path tree looks like:

```
APP
├── _LocationJSONs
|   └── (All 300+ JSONs here)
├── AppDelegate.swift
├── ViewController.swift
├── Main.storyboard
├── LaunchScreen.storyboard
└── Info.plist
```

I need to read in and parse all the JSONs from that local directory, however I don't always know the name.

I've seen `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file name", ofType: "json")` but I can't use that becuase it requires a hard coded name. I've also seen doing something like

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
```

But that just leads to a documents path and I can't seem to get anything from there

Is there any way to 1. Get the path of that directory, and 2. Get the name of all the JSONs that way I can parse them later?

Comment: `FileManager` has methods for get a list of files from a folder. Please review the documentation.

Comment: @rmaddy, wouldn't it be better to use the `Bundle` method `urls(forResourcesWithExtension:subdirectory:localization:)` as described in my answer?

Comment: @DuncanC I didn't know about that method. I've always needed to list files from places outside the bundle.

Comment: For finding files inside the bundle the methods in the `Bundle` class are a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "json", subdirectory: "LocationJSONs")!`

(Might want to do better unwrapping but this works for now)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Bundle` method `urls(forResourcesWithExtension:subdirectory:localization:)` and pass in `subdirectory: "_LocationJSONs"`.

That will let you get a list of all the files inside your "_LocationJSONs" subdirectory that have a given extension (probably "json" in your case)